# Query de SAP HANA no muestra todos los registros en PHP

Tags: php, sql, mvc, sap, hana

He elaborado un query en Hana para SAP B1 que esta funcionando sin problemas, ahora quiero usar ese mismo query para un reporte web elaborado en PHP, sin embargo no muestra toda la información.
Estoy usando el modelo MVC con PHP.

**Conexion.php**
Establece una conexión PDO previamente configurada con el ODBC de Windows, la función `ejecutarConsultaAssoc` se usa para ejecutar las consultas SQL.

```
class Conexion
{
    public static $conexion = null;
    private $db;
    private function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = 'odbc:SAP_HANNA';
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DBUSER, DBPWD);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error de conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public static function getConexion()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$conexion)) {
            self::$conexion = new Conexion();
        }
        return self::$conexion;
    }
    public function ejecutarConsultaAssoc($sql, $array)
    {
        try {
            $sentencia = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $sentencia->execute($array);
            $resultset = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $resultset;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

***Controlador.php***
Aqui esta el query que estoy utilizando.

```
class HannaDAO
{
    private $conexion = null;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conexion = Conexion::getConexion();
    }
    public function consulta($desde, $hasta)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT SF."ID" "ID",
        UPPER(SEDE."Location") "SEDE",
        SF."REFERENCIA_FACTURA_HIS" "ORDEN",
        SF."NUM_FACTURA" "NUMFACTURA",
        SF."ID_PACIENTE" "CEDULAPACIENTE",
        UPPER(USU."CardName") "NOMBREDELPACIENTE",
        SUBSTR(SF."FECHA_CREACION",1,10) "FECHACREACION",
        SF."FECHA_SRI" "FECHASRI",
        SF."USUARIO_CREADOR" "CAJERO",
        EMP."lastName" || \' \' || EMP."firstName" || \' \' || EMP."middleName" "NOMBRECAJERO",
        ROUND(SF."VALOR_TOTAL",2) "VALORTOTAL",
        SF."ESTADO_FACTURACION_ELECTRONICA" "ESTADO",
        SF."TIPO_FACTURA" "TIPOFACTURA",
        SF."AUTORIZACION_SRI" "AUTORIZACIONSRI",
        SF."MENSAJE_SRI" "MENSAJESRI",
        FPAGCAB."U_SYP_NAMEL" "FORMADEPAGO",
        SFP."ID_COD_TARJETA" "REFERENCIA",
        SFP."AUTORIZACION_TARJETA" "LOTE",
        SFP."GIFTCARD_NUM" "GIFTCARD",
        SFP."VALOR_PAGO" "VALORPAGO",
        SF."ID_ASEGURADORA" "RUCASEGURADORA",
        UPPER(USUA."CardName") "ASEGURADORA",
        SF."ID_MEDICO" "CEDULAMEDICO",
        UPPER(SF."NOMBRE_MEDICO") "NOMBREMEDICO",
        UPPER(SF."NOMBRE_ESPECIALIDAD") "ESPECIALIDAD",
        SF."DIAGNOSTICO_PRESUNTIVO" "DIAGNOSTICO",
        SF."CTA_ASOCIADA_CLI",
        PLC1."AcctName" "NOMBRECTA_ASOCIADA_CLI",
        SF."CTA_TRA_ASOC_ASEGURADORA",
        PLC2."AcctName" "NOMBRECTA_TRA_ASOC_ASEGURADORA",
        SF."CTA_TRA_NASOC_ASEGURADORA",
        PLC3."AcctName" "NOMBRECTA_TRA_NASOC_ASEGURADORA",
        SFP."CUENTA_ING_PAGO",
        PLC4."AcctName" "NOMBRECUENTA_ING_PAGO"
        FROM "SIC".SIC_FACTURAS SF
        INNER JOIN "SBO".OLCT SEDE ON SF."CC_SUCURSAL"=SEDE."U_SYP_CIUDAD"
        INNER JOIN "SIC"."SIC_FACTURAS_FORMAS_PAGO" SFP ON SF."ID"=SFP."ID_FACTURA"
        INNER JOIN "SBO"."@SYP_SIC_FPAGCAB" FPAGCAB ON FPAGCAB."Code"=SFP."MEDIO_PAGO"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OCRD USU ON SF."ID_PACIENTE"=USU."CardCode"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OCRD USUA ON SF."ID_ASEGURADORA"=USUA."CardCode"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OHEM EMP ON SF."USUARIO_CREADOR"=EMP."govID"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OACT PLC1 ON SF."CTA_ASOCIADA_CLI"=PLC1."AcctCode"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OACT PLC2 ON SF."CTA_TRA_ASOC_ASEGURADORA"=PLC2."AcctCode"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OACT PLC3 ON SF."CTA_TRA_NASOC_ASEGURADORA"=PLC3."AcctCode"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SBO".OACT PLC4 ON SFP."CUENTA_ING_PAGO"=PLC4."AcctCode"
        WHERE TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(SF."FECHA_CREACION",\'YYYYMMDD\'),\'YYYYMMDD\') BETWEEN \'' . $desde . '\' AND \'' . $hasta . '\' 
        ORDER BY SF."ID" DESC';
        $resulset = $this->conexion->ejecutarConsultaAssoc($sql, array());
        return $resulset;
    }
}
```

Por ultimo presento los registros

```
public function consultar()
{
    $datos = $this->hannaDAO->consultar('2024-01-15', '2024-01-15');
    print_r($datos);
}
```

al ejecutarlo, no me muestra toda la información (cabe aclarar que todos los campos están llenos y deja de mostrar data al llegar a MENSAJESRI):

```
(
    [ID] => 5794
    [SEDE] => CENTRO MEDICO 1
    [ORDEN] => 000003928
    [NUMFACTURA] => 001-029-000000XXX
    [CEDULACLIENTE] => CXXXXXXXXXX
    [CEDULAPACIENTE] => CXXXXXXXXXX
    [NOMBREDELPACIENTE] => NOMBRE PRUEBA PACIENTE
    [FECHACREACION] => 2024-01-15
    [FECHASRI] => 2024-01-15 22:30:41.0000000e
    [CAJERO] => 1234567890
    [NOMBRECAJERO] => NOMBRE DEL CAJERO
    [SUBTOTAL] => 15
    [COPAGO] => 60.000000
    [VALORTOTAL] => 15
    [ESTADO] => F
    [TIPOFACTURA] => 01
    [AUTORIZACIONSRI] => 150120240117927852510012001029000000982123XXXXXXX
    [MENSAJESRI] => 
    [FORMADEPAGO] => 
    [REFERENCIA] => 
    [LOTE] => 
    [GIFTCARD] => 
    [VALORPAGO] => 
    [RUCASEGURADORA] => 
    [ASEGURADORA] => 
    [CEDULAMEDICO] => 
    [NOMBREMEDICO] => 
    [ESPECIALIDAD] => 
    [DIAGNOSTICO] => 
    [CTA_ASOCIADA_CLI] => 
    [NOMBRECTA_ASOCIADA_CLI] => 
    [CTA_TRA_ASOC_ASEGURADORA] => 
    [NOMBRECTA_TRA_ASOC_ASEGURADORA] => 
    [CTA_TRA_NASOC_ASEGURADORA] => 
    [NOMBRECTA_TRA_NASOC_ASEGURADORA] => 
    [CUENTA_ING_PAGO] => 
    [NOMBRECUENTA_ING_PAGO] => 
)
```

Sin embargo si yo comento los campos: MENSAJESRI, LOTE, GIFTCARD, DIAGNOSTICO el query funciona correctamente.

¿Que podría estar sucediendo?
Esos campos contienen texto y números simplemente.

Comment: Hola. ¿Has verificado que en la tabla esa fila tiene datos en `MENSAJESRI` y demás columnas problemáticas? ¿Has verificado que no hay caracteres ocultos, BoM u otras extrañezas en esos datos? En vez de `print_r` convendría que uses `var_dump`, que es más certero. Te dirá lo que hay en cada dato, la extensión de los mismos, etc.

Comment: Correcto, he validado que tenga información, ya que este reporte lo usan en SAP Bussiness One sin problemas, al realizar el `var_dump` se refleja `["MENSAJESRI"]=> NULL` a pesar de que si tiene data.

Comment: Imprime la consulta y pruébala en la BD. No es posible que haya datos y en php tw muestre `NULL`.